E: Package 'php8.3' has no installation candidate
I own a virtual server I installed ubuntu to host in website, I have a problem I want to install php 8.3 but I get this error
E: Package 'php8.3' has no installation candidate
I tried almost all the methods I found online
My Ubuntu version is
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
I followed certain, forums that I found here but they didn't help me.
I tried the following
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt apt update
sudo apt apt upgrade

sudo apt install php8.3
sudo apt install php8.3-cli
sudo apt install php8.3-sqlite3

sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.3

But I get,
E: Package 'php8.3' has no installation candidate
I also used
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php, and all the steps but I get
Package php is a virtual package provided by:
  php8.4 8.4.0~rc1-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [Not candidate version]
  php8.3 8.3.12-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [Not candidate version]
  php8.2 8.2.24-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [Not candidate version]
  php8.1 8.1.30-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [Not candidate version]
  php8.1 8.1.8-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [Not candidate version]
  php8.0 1:8.0.30-9+ubuntu22.04.1.1+deb.sury.org+1 [Not candidate version]
  php7.4 1:7.4.33-15+ubuntu22.04.1.1+deb.sury.org+1 [Not candidate version]
  php7.3 7.3.33-21+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [Not candidate version]
  php8.1 8.1.2-1ubuntu2 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'php' has no installation candidate


All packages are up to date.
W: https://wp-toolkit.plesk.com/cPanel/Ubuntu-22.04-x86_64/latest/wp-toolkit/./InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://wp-toolkit.plesk.com/cPanel/Ubuntu-22.04-x86_64/latest/thirdparty/./InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
root@89-*-*-*:~# sudo apt install php8.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package php8.3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php8.3' has no installation candidate


If your machine is on-line; I'll suggest applying security fixes & upgrades asap, as your details imply you've not applied any since first half of 2023. This link shows the ISO release date of 22.04.3, but installed systems upgraded before that date, 22.04 systems now report themselves as 22.04.5 when fully upgraded...

The server has been online for almost 5 days, I chose the installation through a selection that the reseller offer.
I will follow your indications, thank you.


sudo apt apt update

Most likely it is not working because of double usage of apt.
You can install php8.3 with
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php8.3


I followed your instructions but I get the same answer.

Please edit your question and add the output of sudo apt update.
